# Spatial shifting of Point feature using Vector Bender-Reg

Tags: qgis

I am the new to this QGIS software. I wanted to spatially shift the vector files(Point, Line and Polygon). In that connection, I found this Vector bender plugin and I do. But when I approach Polygon and line features its works perfectly. At the same time, Point features are not working and displaying Python error as "Attribute Error: type object 'Qgis Geometry' has no attribute 'from Point".

How do I do this?